# VS Code Live Server extension not working port 6566

Tags: visual-studio-code, localhost, liveserver

I have a problem with live server extension. I have tried changing default browser (chrome, firefox, edge, ie) and reinstalling extension

Update: Autosave has turned on

Update-2: I tried changing the DNS server to Cloudflare, It didn't work too

[image: Code]

[image: Error Message]

Comment: have you checked : https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/visual-studio-code-live-server-not-working

Comment: Why not have a try with [browser-sync](https://browsersync.io/). It's super easy, and you don't have to make your editor a mess. In which you just save the file, browser will refresh automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try npm live-server or browsersync